# Select two values from two different rows for a single NAME

Tags: mysql

I want to get data from tables where there are more than two (at least 2 are must) values are for a single customer, 1) Debt 2) Debt paid. I need to show these two values according to the maximum date for every customer in a same row. I am using the query below

**QUERY**

```
SELECT MAX(RECEIPTS.DATENEW) AS DATE,
   MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) `TAKEN DEBT`,
   MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) `PAID DEBT`,
   CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER
FROM RECEIPTS
INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
    INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN('debt', 'debtpaid')
GROUP BY RECEIPTS.ID
```

which returns the result as below, seems closer...

[image]

But I need both the debt and debtpaid values to be in the same row for a single customer and with their dates too (individual dates). The required data is something like below image

[image]

Comment: Could you make an http://sqlfiddle.com/ out of this, so we can experiment with the values and the query?

Comment: database is quite big and complicated, just for the idea how to apply that for date thing?

Comment: Only include data that is relevant for testing it, that's how it is supposed to be done. sqlfiddle does not allow posting of full databases.

Comment: I know, thats the reason not putting it there, these tables I am using have very highly coupled with other tables, it's a mess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that worked somehow!
Just a few things to be noticed, as I said there are two entries for each customer so had to group by CUSTOMER and apply the same CASE clause for dates, so just putting the code in case someone may find it helpful.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) AS TAKENDEBT,
    MIN(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) AS GIVENDEBT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' THEN RECEIPTS.DATENEW END) AS TAKENDATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN RECEIPTS.DATENEW END) AS GIVENDATE,
    CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN CUSTOMERS.NAME END AS CUSTOMER 
FROM RECEIPTS
    INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
    INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE
    (PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt'
    OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid')
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
ORDER BY CUSTOMER
```

Thanks for all your suggestions!